# How to get userinfo by jwt token in spring security oauth2 authorization server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I implement a oauth2 authorization server by spring security oauth2 and use `JwtTokenStore` to store access token,then I need to provider a `/userinfo` controller for current access token to get user info by an oauth2 client,the `/userinfo` as follow:

```
 @RequestMapping("/userinfo")
    public Object getCurrentUserInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return authentication;
    }
```

but I don't know how to get userinfo?

Comment: Once a client authenticates it will get an access token, you then need to include the access token in the header (Authorization Bearer ....) when accessing the user info endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe need read more [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) .Know function for `Authorization Server`,`Resource Server` and `OAuth 2.0 Client`,know `spring security`.

To get `userinfo` by access token ,should config a  `resource server` in the `Authorization Server` too. Because `resource server` provider a filter `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`  to get user info by token and set into `SecurityContextHolder`.