# How to get username / userinfo in Spring OAuth2 Resource Server

Tags: spring, azure-active-directory, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have an api which uses AD Token for authorization.
I am trying to fetch the username of the user inside my service component. But im failing to. I have tried this.

```
        val authentication: Authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
        println(authentication.name) // Random short string with 3 "-". Not JWT
        println(authentication.details.toString()) // WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null]
        println(authentication.authorities.toString()) // Prints Scope [SCOPE_User.Read]
        println(authentication.principal) // org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@xxxxxxxx
```

The token is from AD and it does contain userdata. The payload contains these fields with user related stuff. I removed the rest.

```
{,
  "family_name": "Wick",
  "given_name": "John",
  "name": "WickJohn",
  "roles": [
    "User"
  ],
  "scp": "User.Read",
  "unique_name": "wickjo@gmail.com",
  "upn": "wickjo@gmail.com",,
}
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it easily just reading the jwt manually.

```
val authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
val jwt = authentication.principal as Jwt
println(jwt.claims["name"])
```

Still would be interesting to find out why i didnt get it automatically

Answer (score 0):

**To get username/user info in Spring OAuth2 Resource Server, please try the below:**

- Make sure to configure **`resource server`** in the `Authorization Server` too.
- To get user info by token,  `resource server` provides a filter **`OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`**
- The generated token is set into **`SecurityContextHolder`**.
- ***Otherwise***, When accessing **userinfo** try including the access token in the header (Authorization Bearer).

If the above doesn't work, then try using **`On Behalf Of Flow`** and the code mentioned in this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts) blog.

For more information, please **refer** below links:

[Azure AD 2.0 Troubleshooting – OAuth Architecture Guidance (authguidance.com)](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/)

[How to get userinfo by jwt token in spring security oauth2 authorization server? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890622/how-to-get-userinfo-by-jwt-token-in-spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server)